# Implement an algorithm in bash

Tags: linux, algorithm, bash, shell, implementation

I have the following algorithm, and I want to implement it in `bash`.

```
void wepkey64(char *passphrase, unsigned char k64[4][5])
{
    unsigned char pseed[4] = {0};
    unsigned int randNumber, tmp;
    int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(passphrase); i++)
    {
        pseed[i%4] ^= (unsigned char) passphrase[i];
    }

    randNumber = pseed[0] | (pseed[1] << 8) | (pseed[2] << 16) | (pseed[3] << 24);

    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            randNumber = (randNumber * 0x343fd + 0x269ec3) & 0xffffffff;
            tmp = (randNumber >> 16) & 0xff;
            k64[i][j] = (unsigned char) tmp;
        }
    }
}
```

What's the equivalent of this function in `bash`?

Comment: which shell? bash has [bitwise arithmetic operators](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Arithmetic)

Comment: looking to implement it for `sh` and not for bash neither for ksh

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the /bin/sh on your system is actually the Bourne Shell? On many systems /bin/sh is actually the Boune-Again SHell (bash).. You can check with:

```
sh --version
```

If you have access to `gawk`, it has bitwise operators described here: http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bitwise-Functions.html

I think the original `awk` may lack these operators. But again, like `sh` and `bash`, `awk` usually is `gawk` on many systems.

Comment: I m using OpenWRT linux distrubution. it's embedded linux distribution and it does not contain bash and neither gawk

Comment: I checked my linux and it contains bash I updated my question

Answer (score 0):

Here's an awk solution

wepkey.awk

```
BEGIN{for(n=0;n<256;n++)ord[sprintf("%c",n)]=n}{print ord[$1]}

{
  passphrase=$1

  pseed[0]=0
  pseed[1]=0
  pseed[2]=0
  pseed[3]=0

  for (i=0; i<length(passphrase); i++)
  {
    pseed[i%4] = xor(pseed[i%4], ord[substr(passphrase,i+1,1)])
  }

  randNumber = or( or( or(pseed[0], lshift(pseed[1],8)), lshift(pseed[2],16)), lshift(pseed[3], 24))

  for (i=0; i<4; i++)
  {
    for (j=0; j<5; j++)
    {
      randNumber=and(randNumber * 0x343fd + 0x269ec3, 0xffffffff)
      tmp=and(rshift(randNumber, 16), 0xff)
      printf "%02X", tmp
    }
    printf "\n"
  }
}
```

to run it

```
echo passphrase | awk -f wepkey.awk
```